# tensorflow model im2txt: error when using Bazel build "couldn't determine target from filename"

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

In trying to use the im2txt Tensorflow model, I get this error:

couldn't determine target from filename 'im2txt/download_and_preprocess_mscoco'

Here is the link to the Github repo where the model is located:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/im2txt

I'm following the directions from the tutorial/readme.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It had to do with the path to the directory with the IM2TXT models.  As long as you are running the command from the correct directory that you downloaded the models to, the error goes away.

Comment: And then I had to fix '//devtools/python/blaze:pytype.bzl' does not have a corresponding package.